# MVN plugin to ignore test in unmodified submodules

Tags: software-testing, git, plug-in, maven

I have a Maven project that has several submodules. because we have dependencies between some of them, we need to run the build from the parent pom.

Because there are a lot of unit tests the build takes a long time. 
sometimes we are only modifying a single module but we need to wait for everything to build and run tests.

I have an idea of using git diff to ignore the test in unmodified submodules. I started with a python program and I can get the diff and find the modules with changes.

but this will require a separate program to run and execute mvn.

So I started thinking about doing a plugin for mvn that either extends or is a dependency to `maven-surefire-plugin`.

Is this possible can I change the behavior of another mvn plugin.
I not familiar with developing mvn plugin. I wanted to get feedback from people with experience on it or find out if there is another solution.

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question directly. However, I believe you could use the `-pl` flag to build only those modules that you actually modified.

Something like - `mvn -pl library1 clean install`, would cause only the submodule `library1` to be built and installed.

Related/helpful StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606907/maven-build-only-one-module-out-of-multi-module-project/41232647).